# How does a single-stranded RNA bind to a double-stranded DNA to form a "triplex structure"?

Tags: rna

If you have a single-stranded RNA that is complementary to a double-stranded DNA, how do they interact to form what my prof. calls a "triplex structure"?

e.g.

```
    UGCUGAUAGCUACG
ACGTACGACTA
TGCATGCTGAT
```

I don't understand how the DNA can form 2 bonds there?

Comment: None of those sequences are RNA. I assume it's the one at the top that is supposed to be?

Comment: Sorry I fixed that, yes the one on top is RNA

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DNA-RNA triplex formation is well-documented. It was originally analysed in simple model polynucleotides where the DNA has a polypurine strand and the RNA has a polypyrimidine, e.g.

```
rCCCCCC
dGGGGGGGGGGGGGG   
dCCCCCCCCCCCCCC

rUUUUUU
dAAAAAAAAAAAAA
dTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

but it is now known to occur in more complex sequences. One of the best studied examples is in the promoter of the human DHFR gene:

> Gee, J. E. et al.(1992) Triplex formation prevents Sp1 binding to the dihydrofolate reductase promoter. J. Biol. Chem. 267, 11163–11167

[image]

In this work the oligonucleotide GR19 was shown to bind in a triple helix to SpI binding site I in the DHFR promoter (CR19 was used as a control). Triplex formation was detected by gel shift, and the specificity was confirmed by DNase I footprinting.

This effect is part  of the regulation of DHFR - the transcript from a minor upstream promoter binds to the major promoter, see:

> Martianov, I. et al. (2007) Repression of the human dihydrofolate reductase gene by a non-coding interfering transcript. Nature 445: 666-670

The structure of these triple helices involves a combination of Watson-Crick base pairing in the DNA duplex together with [Hoogsteen base pairing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoogsteen_base_pair) in the RNA-DNA interaction:

[image]

Figure taken from:

> Morgan, A. R. & Wells, R. D. (1968) Specificity of the three-stranded complex formation between double-stranded DNA and single-stranded RNA containing repeating nucleotide sequences. J. Mol. Biol. 37, 63–80